BiCGSTAB does not speed up with OpenMP
I want to use OpenMP with Eigen BiCGSTAB solver.
The documentation of Eigen says it is supported, but I cannot figure out why it's not reducing the time of solving linear equations.
This is the snippet of code I am using:
SparseMatrix<double, RowMajor> A(n, n);
// filling in A matrix

int n_t = 8;
omp_set_num_threads(n_t);
BiCGSTAB<SparseMatrix<double, RowMajor>> solver;
solver.setTolerance(1e-10);
solver.setMaxIterations(1000);
solver.compute(A);
VectorXd x = solver.solve(b);

I am compiling the code with following settings:
g++ -I "C:/CPP/eigen-3.4.0" -o parallel_solve -O3 -fopenmp solver_test_parallel.cpp
I am performing a test for the matrix size n=1e6 and both serial and OpenMP version take around 15s to solve the set of equations.
I am compiling the code on Windows.
I have tried using different ways of setting number of threads, downloaded once again eigen but nothing helped. Also, I know there are similar threads about this issue on stack, but none of the solutions helped me.

From looking at the code, the only parallelization that I can find are A * vector sparse-matrix x dense-vector multiplications. All of them are in the solve step, not the compute (which is just the preconditioner). See if a simple matrix-vector multiplication is parallelized for you. Also, have you checked the final result? Maybe the solver gave up before it did any serious computations. Or it finishes very quickly and your bottleneck is somewhere else

Ok, here is a suggestion: all your runtime is taken by constructing the matrix. Try remove the solver and see what your runtime is.

I am measuring only the time of solving.
start = omp_get_wtime();
VectorXd x = solver.solve(b);
end = omp_get_wtime();
